# Constrain random 10-bit such that there won't be 7 consecutive 0s or 1s

Tags: constraints, verilog, system-verilog

Let's say there is one rand 10-bit variable named `data`.  I want to make sure there won't be 7 consecutive 0s or 1s. Can someone suggest to me how can I constraint in such a way?

```
constraint c_data
{
    foreach(data[i]) 
    {
        (data[i] && data[i+7]) == 0;  
    }
}
```

But then array will be out of bound when `i` is greater than 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an implication to keep the indexes bounded

```
parameter width = 7;

constraint c_data
{
    foreach(data[i]) 
    {
        (i < data.size() - width) -> !(data[i+:width] inside {'0,'1});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to avoid values like `10'b0000000111` or `10'b1111111000`:

```
class foo;
    rand bit [9:0] data;
    constraint c_data {
        !(data[9:3] inside {'0, '1});
        !(data[8:2] inside {'0, '1});
        !(data[7:1] inside {'0, '1});
        !(data[6:0] inside {'0, '1});
    }
endclass

module tb;
    foo foo;
    initial begin
        foo = new();
        repeat (10_000) begin
            if (!foo.randomize()) $error;
            $displayb(foo.data);
        end
    end
endmodule
```